# Take data from different tables and display it in View Index in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 tables `Work_table` and `Employee_table`.I want to display `emp_id` from `Work_table` and corresponding `emp_name` from `Employee_table` in the index view of `Employee_table`.
my models are:

```
namespace MvcConQuery.Models
{
[Table("Work_Table")]
public class EnquiryModel
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Int32 Enq_id { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name="Name")]
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
[ReadOnly(true)]
public string Date
{
get
{
DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
return Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); ;
}
set{}
}
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Region")]
public string Region { get; set; }
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone number format is not valid.")]
[Display(Name = "Phone number")]
public string Ph_No { get; set; }
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Display(Name = "Email_id")]
public string Email_id { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Address")]
public string Address { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Query")]
public string Query { get; set; }
public string Referral { get; set; }
public string Feedback { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
public Int32? Emp_id { get; set; }
public string FollowUpDate { get; set; }
public List<EmployeeModel> Employees { get; set; }
}}


namespace MvcConQuery.Models
{
[Table("Employee_Table")]
public class EmployeeModel
{

[Key,Column(Order=0)]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
//[ForeignKey("EnquiryModel")]
public Int32 Emp_id { get; set; }
public string Emp_Name{ get; set; }
//[Key,Column(Order=1)]
public string Region { get; set; }
//[ForeignKey("Region")]
public string Emp_PhNo { get; set; }
public string Emp_Address { get; set; }
public List<EnquiryModel> Enquires { get; set; }


}

}
```

How to write controller?
I stucked when writing the function in controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Please suggest a solution. thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Where are you stuck? What was your attempt? Share your code and let us know.

Comment: I stucked when writing the function                                  public ActionResult Index(){} in controller.

Comment: Is it possible to use another ViewModel class to join data from different tables

Comment: Yes, you need to create a `ViewModel`(with properties as per your need) to render data to the view. In the `index` action you need to join the two tables `Work` and `Employee`. As far as I can make out you should have a 1 -to - * relationship between `Work` and `Employees`. So in your index action you will need to fire a query that will join these two tables on `EmployeeId` and then bind the data to the corresponding properties in the `ViewModel` and then pass that to the view. I will try and put up something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was wrong earlier, I made out from your code that there is a many -to- many relationship between `Employee` and `Work` tables. For my convenience, I have used `Job` as the name for your `Work` table / model.

I hope that you want to display a list of `EmployeeIds` along with the corresponding `EmployeeNames` in the Index View. I have added an extra property called `JobName` to viewmodel, you can have other properties too.

For that matter, create a ViewModel `EmployeeViewModel` and bind the `index view` of your action result with an `IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel>`. The definition for `EmployeeViewModel` can be something like -

```
    public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeName  { get; set; }

        public string JobName { get; set; }

        //..Other memberVariables..
    }
```

Suppose these are your models - 
 
 `Employee`

```
        public class Employee
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

            public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

            public string Address { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
        }
```

And `WorkTable`, *renamed* it as `Job` for my own convenience

```
    public class Job
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int JobId { get; set; }

        public string JobName { get; set; }

        public JobCategory JobCategory { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

In your Index Action, you create a result set by joining the two tables, bind it to `IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel>` and pass that as a model to the view. The View should receive a model of type `IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel>` as I mentioned earlier,so you need to query your entities which should be something like -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //..something like this..this is IQueryable..
        //...convert this to IEnumerable and send this as the model to ..
        //..the Index View as shown below..here you are querying your own tables, 
        //.. Employee and Job,and binding the result to the EmployeeViewModel which
        //.. is passed on to the Index view.
        IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel> model=null;
        model = (from e in db.Employees
                    join j in db.Jobs on e.EmployeeId equals j.EmployeeId
                    select new EmployeeViewModel
                    {
                        EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                        EmployeeName = e.EmployeeName,
                        JobName = j.JobName
                    });

        return View(model);
    }
```

Your index view should be something like -

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.EmployeeViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

*In this above solution, I have made an attempt to generate a situation similar to yours and address your concerns. I hope this brings some sort of respite to your worries and helps you move ahead. Take this as a map and try follow the routes to find your own destination/solution. Btw, sorry for this delayed reply. Hope this helps.*

Comment: I got an error in controller:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcConQuery.Models.Employee viewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Yes thats what I commented out..its `IQuertable`,you need to convert that to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Nivya The main idea is you execute your logic there or call your methods from the repositories in the `ActionResult`.

Comment: Yes I convert it,Now it is working.Thank You very much.

Comment: What about accessing the an already defined SQL View?  I'm not going to have direct read access to all tables.  I just need to read a view, no updates.  `modelBuilder.Entity<DataSubmissionCycle>().ToTable("vw_DataSubmissionCycle");`

Answer (score 0):

This code has something missing *select new EmployeeviewModel*

```
model = (from e in db.Employees
                    join j in db.Jobs on e.EmployeeId equals j.EmployeeId
                    select new EmployeeViewModel
                    {
                        EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                        EmployeeName = e.EmployeeName,
                        JobName = j.JobName
                    });
```