# Mapping model to a SQL view

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I've known how to map a model to a table in SQL in MVC using this:

```
[Table("table_name")]
```

I found this answer [Take data from different tables and display it in View Index in mvc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037603/take-data-from-different-tables-and-display-it-in-view-index-in-mvc4)
. The answer was to create a new model on joining tables in SQL then bind columns to model's fields.

However, can I make it easier by mapping my models to SQL views? Since views are considered to be (virtual) tables and they already contain what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can map an entity to a view.  EF doesn't know or care whether the object is a table, view, synonym or external table.  You just need to map the entity to the view name, and declare the key columns.  Views don't really have key columns, so just use whatever combination of columns uniquely identifies a row in the view results.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I thought I would waste my views.